# Program type already present: kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.EventLoopBase

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle, kotlinx.coroutines

I am getting the following errors in my kotlin android app

> **Android issues: (3 errors)**
>   Program type already present: kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.EventLoopBase
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.EventLoopBase, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
>   Program type already present: kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.internal.LockFreeLinkedListNode
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.internal.LockFreeLinkedListNode, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
>   Program type already present: kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.internal.LockFreeMPSCQueueCore
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.internal.LockFreeMPSCQueueCore, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
>   **Java compiler: (4 errors)**
>   Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /home/deepak/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core/0.25.0/5664ba2d20c6dcc88c912cc9666baa7f03203bcd/kotlinx-coroutines-core-0.25.0.jar
>   Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
>   Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
>   Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException

Below is my dependencies and kotlin experimental coroutine

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'

implementation 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko:0.10.5'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:0.25.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'
}

kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines "enable"
    }
}
```

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: No Not really, since I have backup of my project so I deleted the project and now using the backed-up file. And its working.

Comment: thanks for your reply. so, this is a build bug? do you have any changes in code in your backup project?

Comment: No, instead, due to some git commit problem I backed it up and then made new project and then lazily I copied the code from original project and then I faced this issue.

Answer (score 5):

It is a [bug](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/510) introduced in `kotlinx.coroutines` 0.25.0.

Version 0.25.0 was shipped in the form of [multi-release JAR](https://www.javaworld.com/article/3184029/java-language/java-9s-other-new-enhancements-part-4-multi-release-jar-files.html) and such JAR breaks literally all Android tooling except newest alpha versions.
This change was reverted in version 0.25.3, so updating `kotlinx.coroutines` version and invalidating caches is enough to fix the issue.

Comment: Moving to version `0.25.3` seem to fix this for me.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after lot of combinations and research I found a solution for this but certainly it's not a permanent solution.

I found out that using the two dependency *Kotlin Coroutine* and *androidx* dependencies at the same time causing the problem
So, I removed both of them, and now I am using the android dependencies instead of androidx. Now, my dependencies look like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko:0.10.5'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-design:0.10.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'
}
kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines "enable"
    }
}
```

Thanks to [@Sayem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1263362/sayem) for the help

***happyCoding!***

Comment: I had a similar error using coroutines 0.25.0
It went away when I reverted to 0.23.4

Answer (score 0):

You can use version 0.21 instead of 0.25.0

```
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:0.21'
```